Using a Web Component in a PopUp Window doesn't work in Firefox
TLDR
Adding a web component in a pop-out window works as expected in Chrome / Edge. But in Firefox, before I add the web component to the dom it's functioning, but just afterwards it reverts back to HTMLElement and the web component's internal methods stop being recognized.
Here is a fiddle that is a simplified reproduction of this issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/2avd0un4/
Scenario
I have a two-screen app, the main window is basically an editor, and the second optional pop-up window is a preview. I'm using web components for most of the custom controls.
Problem
I mainly use Chrome / Edge, where this scenario works fine (web components are used as expected in the pop-up window). I did some testing in Firefox, and this issue was identified. I can programmatically create a web component, and check it's working as expected. A shorthand for this is I check this.constructor.name from inside the component's class when the component is connected. My example component is called "SayHello" which is the expected output.
In my real world project, the web component has a lot of internal methods which I use from inside the class like this.someFunction();.
The problem, in FireFox in the pop-out window, just after I add the web component to the dom with appendChild, the web component stops identifying as a SayHello and starts returning HTMLElement. Because of this, none of the internal methods in the class work, and the whole component basically stops functioning. Before it's added to the dom it's fine. But just after it reverts to HTMLElement.
Ask
Take a look at the Fiddle, it's a simplified version of this. Trying it in Chrome / Edge will work, but it will fail and return HTMLElement in Firefox. Is there any way I can make this work?
Update
Also filed this as a bug in Firefox... but if anyone has an idea about a workaround I'd love to hear it.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1893321

This sounds like something you should definitely file a bugzilla ticket for, too, if one doesn't already exist.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - for sure. I thought I would do a sanity check here first to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Submitting the work-around here as the answer. I created a bug against Firefox, and they saw it was a known issue that was raised 6 years ago. The original bug filer had this as the work around:
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.__proto__ = customElements.get('my-custom-element').prototype;
    this._log();
  }
  
  _log() {
    console.log('It works!');
  }
});

Basically just forcing the prototype to be the correct one once the web component connects.
Apparently this happens when trying to use a web component across any frame (like an iFrame, or a new window).
Original bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1502814

Despite it being kind of a edge case, it's incredible they still haven't fixed this. IMO this shows that Mozilla is really lacking the manpower and financial backing to deal with the amount of work that comes from trying to keep up with the big boys. Which is really unfortunate for a free and diverse internet :(
